# ES2015 Proxy: Assert that proxy is the same as target object

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

Is there an easy way to assert that an object is the target object of a proxy?

```
const o = {};
const p = new Proxy(o, {});
```

Equality operators do not seem to work, [as outlined in this paper on page 6](http://matthias-keil.de/papers/techrep2015-proxy.pdf):

```
o == p; // false
o === p; // false
const q = new Proxy(o, {});
p === q; // false
```

Is there any way to verify that they refer to the same object, other then stringifying and reparsing the object?

**Exemplary use-case:**

I want to compare a proxied node with a non proxied one. Since I create the proxy myself, I know what behavior is to be expected.

```
const nodeList = new Proxy(document.querySelectorAll('div'), {
  get(target, key) { return new Proxy(target[key], {}); }
});

const specificNode = document.querySelector('div[data-target]');

for (const node of nodeList) {
  if (node === specificNode) { doSomethingElse(); } // Never happens, even if specificNode is in the nodeList
}
```

Comment: Why would you care? If you don't know what the proxy does, it might behave like `target` or absolutely not.

Comment: @Bergi See the exemplary use-case above.

Comment: Why not rather do `if ("target" in node.dataset) … else`? And of course, creating the inner proxy without any traps is rather pointless.

Comment: It's just a very simple example. The real-world use-case has proxy traps, but would probably be too much for this SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the proxy yourself, you can also make it comparable. For example give a way to identify its target:

```
const associatedTarget = Symbol();
const p = new Proxy(target[key], {});
p[associatedTarget] = target[key];
return p;

…
if (node[associatedTarget] === specificNode)
```

A better idea might be to give each target a singleton proxy, so that you can get *the* proxy for the specific node and compare it by `===`:

```
const proxies = new WeakMap();
function makeUniqueProxy(t) {
  if (!proxies.has(t))
    proxies.set(t, new Proxy(t, {}));
  return proxies.get(t);
}

const nodeList = new Proxy(document.querySelectorAll('div'), {
  get(target, key) { return makeUniqueProxy(target[key]); }
});

const specificNode = makeUniqueProxy(document.querySelector('div[data-target]'));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

for (const node of nodeList) {
  if (node === specificNode) { doSomethingElse(); } // just works
}
```

This approach also has the very desirable property that `nodeList[0] === nodeList[0]`.

Comment: Using WeakMaps to keep track of the proxies is pretty sweet solution, thank you.